# How to implement mouse dragging in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, drag

How to implement mouse dragging in javascript. Should i write a separate function or is any built in method like 'click, mousedown,...' available

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to drag something, or are you looking for an `ondrag` event?

Comment: at least one way you can do it is set a global variable on click and then only execute what you need to in the mousemove event if the global variable is true.

Comment: Look into jQuery.  It has functions to do it built in.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is your friend. [Check it out](http://jquery.com/), it is truely life changing! :)

Specifically for what you are looking for, [JQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)